# Visual Basic read a text file *included with the application binary*

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, file-io, executable

I'm making a vb application that processes files and lets the user edit them through a user interface, instead of typing into the files themselves. I'm reading the values from one file, allowing the user to modify and check them, and then saving them back into a file again. I'm doing this by loading a template, putting the user's values in, and then saving the filled out template back to the disk. The problem is, when I distribute the application, I need a way for the user to have the template file, which is currently just sitting in the project directory.

Here's a quick little diagram of what happens to the information:

```
Read values from disk -> User edits values -> Values go into template string -> Template string is saved to disk.
```

I was thinking of making a Visual Basic Module that just has the contents of the file as a string, but I was hoping there was a way for me to include the template file along with the application binary (The application.exe file) and just read it from disk at run time?

I'm aware of how to read files from the disk in Visual Basic, but my concern is with making sure that the template file is always in a location I can be certain of, and that I can make sure the user takes the data file with them.

Alternatively, if it can get the template built into the executable, similar to how images and icons are, then that would be ideal. However, I'm not sure how to do that, or how to read the text out of it once it's included there, apart from making a VB module and just pasting the template in, and then escaping all the tabs, newlines, and quotes manually (Which will be a headache.)

One more idea I had, which I can use as a last resort, is to load the file into My.Settings and read it from there, but that doesn't seem like how this is supposed to be done.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, I just made a windows forms application in visual basic and have been working with that up until now. Let me know if you need any more information, I hope I've provided enough.

Comment: Have you tried just including the template in the project? Once you package it up the template should travel.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the user to save the results back to the SAME source template? or it will be saved to an external file?

Comment: You could save the "factory default" as a file or in Settings, which is copied to the user's folder and updated as needed,  When deployed, your app will likely live in `C:\Program Files` and your app will likely not have IO permission there.  Thats what the AppData folders are for,